# Open HTML file in Mac's Text Edit from a web browser

Tags: javascript, html, macos, edit, textedit

I'd like to use Javascript (or perhaps some more suitable script?) to open an HTML file in **Text Edit** (I'm on a mac)

I have a local web page made using Text Edit with different tabs that link to more Text Edit files on the page.

I'd like some way of quickly opening the tabs in Text Edit from my browser, then I could edit the HTML files easily in Text Edit and when I refresh the browser it will display my newly edited tab.

Pretty sure this should be simple but I'm a total beginner at Javascript and apart from going through the W3Schools tutorials, I have no knowledge of JScript per se.

Thank you for any help with this in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think TextEdit has a web listener of that sort, like Twitter for Mac has for Safari. I think you would need AppleScript to be able to do this, and that would only be on your local machine.

Comment: Yes, please read the question. All the files _are local_ I want to have a link which will open an HTML file on my browser (Chrome) in a Text Edit file.

Comment: Well, read my answer then, you might need AppleScript to do this locally. And I really don't think a user has this privilege of editing files this way.

Answer (score 0):

...wat? Just get a good text editor. I recommend Sublime Text 2 or Espresso.